# Can i send delete api request directly in browser url?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am using Fastapi , and this delete request is there , so for my hosted api or be it on localhost can i send directly delete request in browser like url --> http://api/delete/2 .
It gives me a method not allowed response and similar for update and put api as well,
Can i directly do through this way or not, ?

I was trying to send this delete API request through url , but the json response says method not allowed..

Comment: Typing into the browser's address bar only ever triggers a GET request. No, with just the browser's address bar, there's no other kind of request you can trigger.

Comment: what if i change type from delete to get and try the same functionality ?

Comment: Yes…!? You _can_ trigger GET requests from the browser easily. But that's also exactly why you _don't_ want to make destructive actions via GET. If you can delete items via GET, then watch Google delete your entire contents as it indexes your site.

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to use a HTTP client as given in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

By default in browser , api requests are taken as "GET" request . To execute any other type of requests use curl or postman .